# More Questions about Two 2-sphere with points identified.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose I have two 2-spheres $S_1$ and $S_2$ and $p_1, q_1\in S_1$ and $p_2, q_2\in S_2$. Then I identify $p_1$ to $q_1$ and $p_2$ to $q_2$. Let X denote this space.

Here is my previous question: [Two $S^2$ with points identified.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3977253/two-s2-with-points-identified)

Jonathan commented that the possible CW structure is 2 0-cell, $p_1$ on $S_1$ and $p_2$ on $S_2$, two lines $a, b$ and 2-cells via $aa^{-1}$ and $bb^{-1}$.

I want to study this space further by calculating $H_n$ and $H^n$ using two different methods respectively as follows.

My questions are: for all $n\geq 0$,

1. How can we compute $H_n(X)$ by using Mayer-Vietoris sequence and Cellular homology.
2. How can we compute $H^n(X)$ by using cellular cohomology and universal coefficient theorem.

Universal Coefficient Theorem for Cohomology: Hatcher page 195

[image]

I know

1. $H_2(X^2, X^1)=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z},$
2. $H_1(X^1, X^0)=\mathbb{Z},$
3. $H_0(X^0)=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Your space seems to be a disjoint union of two copies of equivalent space? If so, then you may calculate the (co)homology for each component and take the direct sum. Also, your notation $H_0(Y^0)$ seems weird, where is $Y^0$ from?

Comment: @Kevin.S Sorry it is a typo I meant $X^0$ when writing $Y^0$. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Regarding the part after "I know", even if you fix that $Y$ issue, the latter two relationship are still incorrect. $X$ contains two $0$-cells, two $1$-cells, so both of which should be isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}\oplus\Bbb{Z}$. Also, I'm curious about your background of AT since it seems that you know all those theorems but don't quite know how to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comment, we may compute the (co)homology for each component first.

Let $M$ denote one component of your space, then it looks like this (I tried my best...):

[image]

- Since $M$ is connected, $H_0(M)\cong\Bbb{Z}$. For $k>2$, $H_k(M)\cong 0$.
- Take $U\approx B^2$ be an open ball on the attached disk, and $V$ be a nhbd of $M-\overline{B^2}\simeq S^1$ that deformation retracts onto it. So, $U\cap V\approx S^1$.

Consider the non-trivial part of the reduced MV sequence,

$$0\to H_2(M)\overset{\partial_*}{\longrightarrow}H_1(S^1)\overset{(i_*,-j_*)}{\longrightarrow}H_1(S^1)\overset{k_*+l_*}{\twoheadrightarrow} H_1(M)\to 0$$

We just need to know $(i_*,-j_*)$. It's actually a trivial map because if the generator $a\in H_1(U\cap V)$ is represented by $\alpha$, then $i_*:H_1(U\cap V)\to H_1(U), \alpha\mapsto 0$, since $U\approx B^2$. $-j_*:H_1(U\cap V)\to H_1(V), \alpha\mapsto -(\beta-\beta)=0$ for the generator $\beta$ of $H_1(V)$ because $\alpha\sim(\beta-\beta)$ (homologous). Therefore, both $(k_*+l_*)$ and $\partial_*$ are isomorphisms. For the disjoint union $X$, you just take the direct sum.

For cellular homology, I think I can provide a hint with the cellular chain complex
$$0\overset{}{\to}\Bbb{Z}\overset{\partial}{\to}\Bbb{Z}\overset{0}{\to}\Bbb{Z}\to0$$
where the map $\partial$ is related to the attaching map (which you already have)

For cohomology using UCT, note that the short exact sequence splits, which means (Try yourself before click on the spoiler)

> $$H^k(X)\cong \operatorname{Hom}(H_k(X);\Bbb{Z})\oplus\operatorname{Ext}(H_{k-1}(X);\Bbb{Z})$$ For a finite CW complex such that its homology is finitely generated,  $$H^k(X)\cong \operatorname{Hom}(H_k(X);\Bbb{Z})\oplus T_{k-1}(X)$$ $\operatorname{Ext}$ reflects the torsion (in our case, it's torsion-free).

---

It is worth mentioning that $M$ is the deformation retraction of $S^2$ with an arc attaching its north and south pole, which is homotopic equivalent to $S^2\vee S^1$. It would be clearer if we use this to compute its (co)homology.